# What is the difference between primary and alt fire for the Railgun?

Tags: killing-floor-2

The new Sharpshooter perk is out, and with it some new weapons.
I've only had limited experience with the Railgun but to me it seems like the primary and alt fire modes are pretty similar except for maybe locking on to the enemies' weak points.

What are the differences in mechanics between the two fire modes?

Comment: You mean the zoom in function? As in left click is fire and right click is zoom in? Only difference is that by zooming in you can lock on to monsters weakpoints and hit them even while you are not actually aiming at them. Normal is just blind fire, so you can miss.

Comment: I meant the primary/alt fire mechanics. The lock on when viewing down the sights is one difference that's easily noticeable but I wanted to know about other differences such as damage, penetration, trajectory (ie does the locked on bullet curve or shoot straight), etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That exactly it. The primary fire mode has a locking mechanism you can use, but the secondary fire mode turns that off but does 2x the damage. According to the recent update:

Auto lock-on damage decreased to 375

Manual lock on damage 750

Comment: I'm still curious about bullet penetration and/or trajectory. Ie, if you're locked on and not aimed directly at the target, what path will the bullet take and will it penetrate less than manual aiming?

Comment: @PhilD. If you are not aiming directly at the target, but the lock is on then it will still hit. Haven't noticed the trajectory tho, because most of the time it is to hectic to look at the pretty lasers.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with john's answer, I just wanted to add that other than the double/half damage for unassisted/assisted, the trajectory is totally automatic while in assisted mode, only a really lucky lineup will penetrate other zeds (although if you line up a shot normally even though assist is on, it makes no difference)

Basically if you have the time to aim (most cases you can no scope and its fine) then always use unassisted. I am not some CSGO pro that can 180 noscope people, but with some practice i don't use aim assist or even the scope.

This is also due to the time it takes to properly lock on while scoping in assisted mode, i can fire 3 shots without scope and assist in the time it takes a person to fire 1 assisted shot at half the damage. I would recommend never using assisted mode unless its a case like Patriarch is running away